# Keep Games in Full Screen Mode

Tags: assassins-creed

I am playing Assassin's Creed on Windows 7. After I launch the game, suppose I get a pop-up (like Windows Update). Now the game is stuck in windowed mode, and no way to get it back to full screen.

Is there any way to do go back to full screen without restarting the game, or possibly avoid these popups to begin with?

Comment: This sounds more like a Windows problem than a gaming one.  The underlying issue sounds like Windows is doing something or other.  Fix that, and that should do it.

Comment: I'm not sure what that "something or other" is

Comment: I have this software called Advanced SystemCare which has a turboboost function for gaming. It shuts off Windows Updates and unnecessary background functions. As for the fullscreen, there should be a setting in options, or you can right-click the game in Steam, click properties, and set launch options to `-fullscreen`. That should work to my knowledge.

Comment: usually, minimize game and maximize is sufficient.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl-Enter?

Comment: +1 for the minimize / maximize, this usually works. Anyway, it's more about preventing apps from stealing the focus from other ones than stopping the games going into windowed mode: it's not really the games fault. You'll have to configure your other applications not to steal the focus like that. Avast has a silent mode, for instance. I don't know about the Apple software update, but Windows Update never bugged me like that (I have set "check for update but let me choose whether to download and install them").

Comment: @Toto I think he means that Windows Update is bugging him to restart.

Comment: @Doomsknight Minimize/maximize does not work

Answer (score 6):

`Alt + Enter` is the magic combination to solve your problem.

PS: For Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

As Samir stated, Alt + Enter is the Windows key combination to toggle between full screen/windowed mode.

If you want those other unnecessary programs to be automatically disabled when launching a game and then re enabled when exiting a game, I highly recommend you check out [Razer Gamebooster](http://www.razerzone.com/gamebooster). (it's free)

Answer (score 0):

If Alt+Enter does not work, Start+Up can also work.  That's the maximize shortcut.  Start+Left and Start+Right maximize to the right or left side of your screen, and Start+Down minimizes.

Answer (score 0):

Razer Game Booster creates a virtual desktop for you automatically when you start the game, it will avoid getting back to windows 7. It also closes unnecessary processes.